# How to backup MYSQL database with kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I successfully, recreated [Single-Instance Stateful Application](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/) tutorial. Naturally, I'd like to create a periodic backup of all databases. I found this [article](https://medium.com/@madushagunasekara/export-mysql-db-dump-from-kubernetes-pod-and-restore-mysql-db-on-kubernetes-pod-6f4ecc6b5a64) that explains how to make a backup. Unfortunately, it does not work for me. The command that I am running looks like this

```sh
$  kubectl exec -n <namespace> <pod> -- mysqldump -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD --all-databases > /var/lib/mysql/backup/alldbs.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

I found error(s). Backup was not working for two reasons.

1st, incorrect **semantic**. Instead of using `kubectl exec -n <namespace> <pod> mysqldump -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD --all-databases > dump.sql` as article mentions. I had to use a syntax described in [mysql dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) documentation that looks like this `kubectl exec -n <namespace> <pod> -- sh -c 'exec mysqldump --all-databases -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"' > dump.sql`

2nd, incorrect **path assumption**.  I assumed that `dump.sql` was created on the pod/container filesystem so, I expected to see backup file inside container. Instead backup file was created relative to your host machine filesystem not pod/container.